# Validate a csv file against a json schema in python

Tags: python, validation

I have my metadata that look like this example:

```
{
  "metadata_id":"2",
  "flow_properties": {
    "flow_name_index" : 3,
    "flow_name_separator" : "_"
  },
  "flows": [
    {
      "flow_name" : "CONTACT",
      "file_properties": {
        "separator":"¤",
        "encoding-type" : "utf-8"
      },
      "nb_lines": 3,
      "schema" : {
        "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id_contact",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "first_name",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "last_name",
          "type": "string"
        }    
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "flow_name" : "SALES",
      "file_properties": {
        "separator":",",
        "encoding-type" : "utf-8"
      },
      "nb_lines": 6,
      "schema" : {
        "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id_sales",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "description",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "total_price",
          "type": "number"
        }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to validate my files that come from those different flows against the correct schema in the metadata.

My question is: Is there a library in python that takes a json schema, a csv file and do the job?
I already tested `goodtables`, `csvvalidator` and `pycsvschema`. They do not seem to answer my needs, except for `pycsvschema`. However I cannot make it work. For the details about the `pycsvschema`, please check the issue I opened [here](https://github.com/crowdskout/PyCSVSchema/issues/2#issuecomment-538867561).

I also tried to use `pyspark`, but I don't know if that is a good idea if my files are not that big!

Any usefull information would be appreciated!

Comment: Download [pycsvschema/schema.json](https://github.com/crowdskout/PyCSVSchema/blob/master/pycsvschema/schema.json) and try again.

Comment: @stovfl I already did and it does not seem to be the right schema file. Because I get errors of some additional fields that fail to get validated

Comment: Are the `FileNotFoundError:` gone? ***"I get errors of some additional fields that fail to get validated"***: Isn't it the purpose of `pycsvschema` to show that as result?

Comment: @stovfl It is gone. However it does not validate the `pycsvschema/schema.json` file, not the schema of my file

Comment: As i understand, `pycsvschema/schema.json` is supposed to validate your `schema` not the opposite and on call `v.validate()` your `CSV` is validated against your `schema`. I feel these issue becomes to broad for SO, Setup a [GitHub project](https://github.com/join?source=header-home), there I can go supporting you.